# the fileUrl file does not exists in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I **want to open a file url in browser** but the issue I am facing is that the **file fileUrl does not exists**. But when I paste that url in browser it opens the file.

```
 final msg = await OpenFile.open(message.uri);
  log("msg result =${msg.message.toString()}");
```

**output:** msg result = the file fileurl does not exist

the url is : [Url](https://erpnsol.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/public/chatfiles/1642483260my%20ABC.pdf?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIARLMVATOEDLJEOTFS%2F20220118%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220118T052153Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=518400&X-Amz-Signature=7472a61e74c71fc4af93c5397578f13fdc77126eed2c5c73b1b309f9470baed0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the file in the browser use `url_launcher` packages : [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
_launchURL(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: but first I used this url launcher but it not opened.

Comment: Check to see if message.uri has a value? Then you added packages to your project? And put the name space in your widget? If you have done these steps correctly, it must work.

Comment: Yes, I did but can be some issue in code

Comment: I edited answer, I used an async method to open the browser, probably because the problem was not async